# is there any risk using std::addressof(std::cout) instead of &std::cout?

Tags: c++, c++11, sonarqube, c++14

I am using `std::cout` for logging and sonarqube reports error when "Don't take the address of 'cout', call it from a lambda instead".

```
std::ostream *streamp;
streamp = &std::cout;
```

When I use the below code there is no error observed in sonarqube. Is using `std::addressof` on `std::cout` function safe?

```
std::ostream *streamp;
streamp = std::addressof(std::cout);
```

Comment: The safety is same as if you were using `&`; the analyzer is just not smart enough to see what's going on. I wonder what's the reason for this warning...

Comment: This is a very strange warning.  `cout` is a static object and is guaranteed to be initialized before any of your code so getting a pointer to it should be 100% safe.

Comment: I suspect this is a warning trying to catch `[&std::cout](){ cout << "Capturing a name unnecessarily"; }` etc.

Comment: @NathanOliver conceivably a problem if a static object is doing logging during shutdown and `cout` is destroyed before the logger destructs?

Comment: @M.M I don't think that can happen: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/iostream.objects#overview-3.sentence-2

Comment: @NathanOliver  I ran into problem that it "kinda" happened on Windows and some embedded systems. I.e. runtime library closes all files and pipes as soon as `main()` exits far before destruction of  thread\proccess wide objects. But that clearly points at non-compliant  nature of implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, using `addressof` on `std::cout` is safe. But since using `&` on `std::cout` is equally safe, the only reason to do it is to quiet a tool that clearly is giving you a false-positive (that it, it doesn't realize what `addressof` is doing).

It would be better to use `&` and employ whatever mechanisms exist in the tool to turn off false-positives.

Answer (score 2):

`std::cout` is an object, not a function, thus the rules forbidding taking the address of most standard functions don't apply.

`std::addressof()` is only needed where the address-operator might be overloaded (generally a bad thing to even consider), and thus is used in templates to avoid surprises. It is not needed for any standard types, and thus neither objects.

In conclusion, get the tool fixed or ignore that warning, your choice, but don't bend your code into a pretzel.

---

To expand on standard functions,  most functions in the standard library aren't designated "addressable".
Thus, taking their address might result in surprises, all the way from "working" by happenstance, over giving a function-pointer with an unexpected signature (more arguments, unexpected calling-convention, whatever), to failing to compile at all. And that might change with any change to the toolchain.

Comment: I agree with your general analysis, but is it actually the case that since `std::cout` is an object, we don't need to worry about taking the address? In principle it could have an overloaded `&` operator, though my guess (?) is that the standard wouldn't permit that?

Comment: @templatetypedef clarified that the standard types are reasonable in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `&x` and `std::addressof(x)` (for variables of class type) only occurs if `x` has an overloaded `&` operator.

`addressof` is for "no, no, I really want the address of this thing, no matter what the class designer has decreed".

That being said, 99++% of the time `&x` is fine. It's certainly fine for `cout`, since you can look and see that it doesn't have an `operator &`.